# Any way to break up data into array?

Tags: php

**Problem**

So a have some php code that gets student info from the db and outputs that info. The info is outputted in a `input` so the user can edit that info. Then when the user is done editing the info, I need to get the data, which I have. My problem is that I don't know how to break up that info so it's easy for me to alter the info in the db.

**Student Table**

```
studentID | firstname | lastname | teacherID
```

**PHP Code that has the inputs**

```
<form action="server/edit/students.php" method="post">

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Student ID</th>
                            <th>Firstname</th>
                            <th>Lastname</th>
                            <th>Teacher's Firstname</th>
                            <th>Teacher's Lastname</th>
                        </tr>

                        <?php

                            // get student info
                            $getStudent = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM students");
                            $getStudent->execute();
                            $getStudent = $getStudent->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                            $value = 0; // counts rows

                            // loop through each student
                            foreach ($getStudent as $student) {
                                $studentID = $student['studentID'];
                                $firstname = $student['firstname'];
                                $lastname = $student['lastname'];
                                $teacherID = $student['teacherID'];

                                // get teacher
                                $getTeacher = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM teachers
                                                            WHERE teacherID = :teacherID");

                                $getTeacher->execute(array(
                                    "teacherID" => $teacherID
                                ));

                                $getTeacher = $getTeacher->fetchAll();

                                // loop through each teacher
                                foreach ($getTeacher as $teacher) {
                                    $teacherFirstname = $teacher['firstname'];
                                    $teacherLastname = $teacher['lastname'];

                                    // output data
                                    echo "
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><input type='text' name='studentID-$value' value='$studentID'></td>
                                            <td><input type='text' name='firstname-$value' value='$firstname'></td>
                                            <td><input type='text' name='lastname-$value' value='$lastname'></td>
                                            <td><input type='text' name='teacherFirst-$value' value='$teacherFirstname'></td>
                                            <td><input type='text' name='teacherLast-$value' value='$teacherLastname'></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    ";
                                }

                                // add to row
                                $value += 1;

                            }

                         ?>
                    </table>

                    <button type="submit" name="update">Update</button>

                </form>
```

**PHP Code that alters the db**

```
$dataCount = 0;

foreach ($_POST as $data) {
    if($dataCount % 5 === 0) {
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo $data . ", ";
    } else {
        echo $data . ", ";
    }

    $dataCount++;

}
```

**What the form loops like on the screen**

```
StudentID      Firstname      Lastname      Teacher's Firstname      Teacher's Lastname
_______________________________________________________________________________________
1              Bill           Roy           Jonathan                 Kung
2              Travis         Roy           Shanin                   Harnik
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Isn't the $_POST variable an array with the data?

Comment: But I don't know how to break up that info so it's easy for me to alter the info in the db.

Comment: `"UPDATE students SET Firstname='{$db->real_escape_query($_POST['Firstname'])' WHERE StudentID='{$_POST['StudentID']}'"`

Comment: The above is just a pseudocode. You should get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is use an array name in your input fields. This way your `$_POST` will be in a bunch of grouped arrays that are easily looped through:

```
<form action="server/edit/students.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Student ID</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Teacher's Firstname</th>
            <th>Teacher's Lastname</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        // get student info
        $getStudent = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM students");
        $getStudent->execute();
        $getStudent = $getStudent->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $value = 0; // counts rows
        // loop through each student
        foreach ($getStudent as $student) {
            $studentID = $student['studentID'];
            $firstname = $student['firstname'];
            $lastname = $student['lastname'];
            $teacherID = $student['teacherID'];
            // get teacher
            $getTeacher = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE teacherID = :teacherID");

            $getTeacher->execute(array(
                "teacherID" => $teacherID
            ));

            $getTeacher = $getTeacher->fetchAll();
            // loop through each teacher
            foreach ($getTeacher as $teacher) {
                $teacherFirstname = $teacher['firstname'];
                $teacherLastname = $teacher['lastname'];
                // output data
                ?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' name='student[<?php echo $studentID ?>][firstname]' value='<?php echo $firstname ?>' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='student[<?php echo $studentID ?>][lastname]' value='<?php echo $lastname ?>' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='student[<?php echo $studentID ?>][teacherFirst]' value='<?php echo $teacherFirstname ?>' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='student[<?php echo $studentID ?>][teacherLast]' value='<?php echo $teacherLastname ?>' /></td>
        </tr>
                <?php
            }
            // add to row
            $value += 1;
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" name="update">Update</button>
</form>
```

When processing the `$_POST` you loop through the `$_POST['student']` array and the keys will be the ids and the rest of the data is contained in the array.